# Twitter API Library for .Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

does anyone know if there is a Twitter API library for the .Net Compact Framework. I want to use Linq to Twitter but unfortunatly it will not work with the Compact Framework, I can´t deploy to a device because it seems to use too many libraries of the Desktop Framework.

Do you have any idea for a library that works with the Compact Framework?

Thank you

thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NTwitter](http://ntwitter.codeplex.com/):

> a lighwight C# Twitter API encapsulation for .NET Framework 2.0 and Compact Framework 2.0 and above

Comment: I think there might by no support for the oAuth twitter login. Please correct me if I'm wrong!